# How do I avoid cumulative filetype commands in vim?

Tags: vim, file-type, vim-plugin, ftplugin

Let's say I load up a python file in vim. A quick check of `:scriptnames` shows that my `~/.vim/ftplugin/python/python.vim` file loads as expected. One of the commands in this file highlights all characters that are past the 80th column. Now lets say I open a C++ file in another buffer (therefore running `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp/cpp.vim`). Although the new commands are executed, the settings in `python.vim` still apply; therefore characters are highlighted past the 80th column in my C++ file.

Is there anyway to make filetype commands not cumulative like this? I have `filetype plugin indent on` in my `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that both `'colorcolumn'` and `:match` (you didn't specify whether you use the new setting or the older highlight approach) are **local to the window**, but ftplugins should only set *buffer-local* settings.

Why are these settings window-local? That allows you to have the same buffer displayed in two windows, one with, and one without the highlighting.

What can you do to prevent this?

a) Don't set this in the ftplugin, and instead use mappings to toggle the colorcolumn on/off.

b) Put `:setlocal nocolorcolumn` into all ftplugin scripts (e.g. in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/*.vim`) for all filetypes that you're using. This will only work unless you switch between different filetypes in the same window.

c) The correct (but most complex) way to solve this is through a couple of `:autocmd`s on `BufWinEnter`, `BufWinLeave`, and `WinLeave` events.

Comment: Is this the case with some other commands? For example, setting the font, or even plugin-specific commands such as changing the default completion type in SuperTab. Basically I want to have one list of commands for all filetypes, and another that only applies to buffers that are currently displaying particular filetypes. Is your (c) suggestion the best way to go about this? If so, can you elaborate a little more about it? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the setting. Check out `:help 'settingname'`, you'll find _local to ..._ hints there. For plugin-specific commands, they're usually global; for their config, you see the scope in the variable being used: `g:...` is global, `b:` is buffer-local.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the affecting scope of the commands I am setting and make changes based on your suggestions.